# Detect when cut-ed data is being pasted in MFC COleDataSource VS2008

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2008-sp1, cut-and-paste

I need to detect when another application /window in my app does paste on my previously set data , so I can remove it from my source window. I have discovered that `COleDataSource::DelaySetData` *theoretically* does this and `COleDataSource::OnSetData` would get called when paste occurs, but I can not be sure. MSDN is (as usually) vague about this matter and does not clearly say one way or the other.I will be using an custom format and watever format is explorer using for cut/paste files.
So the question is how EXACTLY (not theoretically) can this be done.
I really need to remove the items from my window **if and only if** they are pasted somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it all wrong. When you Cut something it's supposed to be deleted immediately, and you should provide an undo function if it needs to be restored.

The clipboard was not designed for bidirectional signalling. DelaySetData is intended for applications which are submitting large amounts of data in different formats, so that they only need to provide the format which is required by the receiver; using it to detect when a paste occurs is relying on a side effect. There are clipboard managers which might make this fail.

Comment: I am sorry but you are wrong.Very wrong.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969396.aspx#delete_on_paste. I do not support undo in my application. Adding this feature costs immensely at this point. And, as you can see from the link above even Microsoft does this.If you "cut" something from explorer the files/directories do not get deleted immediately. They are deleted only _after_ an paste operation has been done.